# File ".stats" when run python in Neovim

Tags: python, file, ide, neovim, nvim-lspconfig

I'm a beginner for Neovim recently I have a problem that is when I run any python file immediately after that in my local folder auto-create a new file that has end file name is ".stats".I posted this post wishes someone to can help me. Thank u for reading.

Here my image example:
[image]

Here is my init.vim link:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/thep200/python/blob/master/init.vim)

Answer (score 1):

These files generated by `pylint`. If you have any plugin for auto-linting, which use this linter (such as `ALE`), `.stats` files will be generated each time you open/save python files, depending on the plugin settings.
If you want to continue using this linter, you can disable generating `.stats` files by specifying the `persistent` `pylint` option as `n` ([default is `y`](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/features.html?highlight=persistent#general-options)).
You can also try to set environment variable `PYLINTHOME` to point to your directory ([FAQ](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/faq.html#where-is-the-persistent-data-stored-to-compare-between-successive-runs)), but there may be a problem with it.
And of course, if you want, you can exclude this linter from the list in the your plugin settings.

[More about what the 'persistent' option does.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475327/how-does-pylint-remember-scores-from-previous-runs)

The problem is, most likely, in the interaction of the calling plugin and the called `pylint`, because behavior with generating `.stats` files in the same directory with the checked files only works in this case. If you call the `pylint` check yourself, without nvim plugin, these files will be generated as declared in [FAQ](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/faq.html#where-is-the-persistent-data-stored-to-compare-between-successive-runs).

Answer (score 0):

Previously, I was using pylint 2.9, which has this issue. I upgraded pylint to 2.15.5, now the issue is gone. Pylint now stores the stats file in cache directory instead of polluting the user's project directory. See [here](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/faq.html#where-is-the-persistent-data-stored-to-compare-between-successive-runs) for the location of cache directory.

So the simple answer for now is to upgrade pylint:

```
pip install -U pylint
```